# Can't create RESTful streamed WCF service

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I'm trying to create a RESTful WCF service, but it uses Streamed transfer because it is transferring large files.
There are many examples online and they all seem to end up with one approach. I just can't get it to work!

I have created this contract interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://services.mydomain/MyService", ConfigurationName = "MyService")]
public interface IMyServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    Stream GetFile(string someValue, string filepath);
}
```

And the following implementation of the contract:

```
public class MyServiceImpl : IMyServiceContract
{
    public Stream GetFile(string someValue, string filepath)
    {
        DoSomethingWith(someValue);
        return File.OpenRead(filepath);
    }
}
```

Finally I create the WCF service like this (I can't put anything in app.config because this is started dynamically, so everything must be started programatically without any dependencies on app.config):

```
private void StartService()
{
    MyServiceImpl svcImplementation = new MyServiceImpl();
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(svcImplementation, "http://localhost/MyService");

    ServiceBehaviorAttribute behaviour = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
    behaviour.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;

    WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding
    {
        TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
        ReaderQuotas = { MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue }
    };

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyServiceContract), binding, "MyService")
        .Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
    {
        HttpGetEnabled = true
    };
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    host.Open();
}
```

Everything compiles, and everything starts without any errors.
When I, in Postman, try to access `http://localhost/MyService/GetFile?someValue=foo&filepath=C%3A%5Ctemp%5Csomefile.txt` I seem to get a HTTP 405, which says that only POST is allowed (even though I have decorated the method with `[WebGet]`

If I get Postman to POST instead of GET, I get a HTTP 404.

If I go to `http://localhost/MyService` in a browser I get the standard WCF service page, so the service is definitely running.

Adding `UriTemplate` to the `[WebGet]` attribute has no effect:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{someValue}/{filepath}")]
Stream GetFile(string someValue, string filepath);
```

Based on the examples I've found I feel like this should be easy, but I must be missing something essential as I just can't get it to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36973/Stream-Operation-in-WCF)

Comment: That's a 7.5 year old post. Surely something must have been updated since then. Especially as there are many examples of streamed REST online, even with `WebHttpBinding`. It's just that I can't get the examples to work.

Comment: Have you tried making some kind of "testing application" or only through web requests?

Comment: Only through web requests as that is what it must support.

Comment: Okay, last thing. Can you show Web.Config file?

Comment: There is no web.config file as this is a selfhosted service, and everything must be configured from code.